# Sencha cmd 6.1 makes app size bigger

Tags: android, ios, cordova, sencha-touch-2, sencha-cmd

I have a sencha touch-cordova app which supports ios and android. I observed a weird thing - with exactly same code base and files if I use sencha cmd 6.0.2.14 the resulting app size is just 22.5 MB while if I build it using sencha cmd 6.1.1, the app size jumps to 77 MB.

I am new to sencha and am really curious to know how the cmd version affects the size of resulting app.

I am using `sencha app build native` command to build the app and the target platforms are mention in app.json as usual.

Would be great if someone points out the difference in the cmd version affecting the size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have had build issues with 6.1.1 and 6.1.2.

For 6.1.2 the generate app command will copy over all the example and template files into your application causing massive build times. Both versions have caused use issues during the slicing portion of the build process with Java heap and Array out of bounds errors.

As a result we have concluded 6.1.1 isn't usable and have rolled back to an older version of CMD.